# After updating to xCode 8 and iOS 10 UIWebview ceased to play video *.mp4

Tags: objective-c, ios10

After updating to xCode 8 (and correspondingly it updated to ios 10) I get following in the console:

```
!DidFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=204 "Plug-in handled load" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://blahblahblah.com/BH2.mp4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://blahblahblah.com/BH2.mp4, WebKitErrorMIMETypeKey=video/mp4, NSLocalizedDescription=Plug-in handled load}

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Problem is in playing a video. And the fact is that these videos are reproduced via the phone browser, but via my app - no.

**Before everything worked..**
Snippet of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString* strUrl = @"https://blahblahblah.com/BH2.mp4";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    self.request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [self.webView setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback:YES];
    self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"Did start loading: %@ auth:%d", [[request URL] absoluteString], _authenticated);
    NSLog(@"REQ: %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    if (!self.authenticated) {
        self.authenticated = NO;
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];
        [task resume];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.view.alpha = 1.f;
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"!DidFailLoadWithError: %@", [error description]);
    self.view.alpha = 1.f;
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
        _authenticated = YES;
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }

    [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];
}
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I ran into something similar, and it had to do with missing intermediate certs. Assuming your SSL cert is valid and not expired, it might still fail to validate if the intermediate certs are not available. Make sure your web server is serving the intermediate cert for your SSL site (in apache the conf directive is SSLCertificateChainFile). And as for why it worked before and stopped working in Xcode 8, Apple is constantly tightening security policies with every update.